# How do I get rid of the ugly Horizontal Scroll bar in this layout?

Tags: css

I feel like such a noob asking this but, for some reason a horizontal scroll bar appeared out of NOWHERE.

**How do I get rid of the ugly horizontal scroll bar at the bottom?**

CSS Style Sheet File: [style_sample.css](http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/style_sample.css)

Web page: http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/sample.html

This website is a great learning resource for hands-on experience. I'm learning as I go.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrollbars on that page. What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: I don't see any ugly scroll bars.  Only my beautiful system scroll bar.

Comment: Jcubed I'm using Mozilla Firefox on a 1280 x 768 laptop screen.

Comment: Links are dead.  Post the code or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Hello. This was posted 4 years ago I see. I ended up picking on of the answer options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the CSS `overflow-x:hidden;` to your `<body>` element.

Comment: This worked BEAUTIFULLY. Thank you. I'm saving this in my memory lol

Comment: This is still the wrong way to do this.  Instead of addressing the symptoms you should be addressing the source.

Comment: It's not necessarily the "wrong way to do this." If it works with their particular layout then it's completely valid.

Comment: -1 This is not a good solution. You should fix the problem, not the symptomes.

Answer (score 1):

You have put margins on the footer to center it, then you have moved it to the right 250px using relative positioning, so it sticks out to the right.

Use either margin or relative positioning on it.

Comment: *Smacks forhead* Thank you Guffa! This helps reinforce the lesson on proper positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your gridview embedded within a panel, make sure that the width of the panel is greater than the width of the gridview.  If the gridview width is greater or equal the width of the panel plus the width of the vertical scrollbar (if you specified one), the horizontal scroll bar will always be there.  In my case, the vertical scroll bar is 20px wide.  For example, this will always cause the horizontal scrollbar:

```
<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" Width="1200px" ScrollBars="Vertical" 
      Height="500px">
    <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1200px" 
                        Height="500px" HeaderStyle-Height="34px">
```

Whereas this will not:

```
   <asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" Width="1200px" ScrollBars="Vertical" 
          Height="500px">
        <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1180px" 
                            Height="500px" HeaderStyle-Height="34px">
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your browser window wider.  It probably "just appeared" because your window isn't maximized anymore - **unless you changed something in the stylesheet or layout**, in which case, that change made the page wider.

It looks like you added a `left:` element to `p:footer-text`.  Remove that, and if you want to center your text, make it `text-align:center;` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful. I think a change in my style sheet did add the horizontal scroll bar. Because before it wasn't there.

Comment: "Make your browser window wider" is not a solution to this problem, or *any* CSS-related problem for that matter.

Comment: I was replying to the original question which said "This scroll bar appeared out of nowhere" - I wanted to point out that the scroll bar can appear for reasons other than changes to stylesheet or HTML. Definitely didn't mean to imply that it's a solution to the problem, but meant it as "maybe this is why you are seeing this behavior you didn't see before."